# Rspec and Nokogiri ignoring response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am writing tests with rspec testing a response with nokogiri.  However, although when I run the method in the console it works perfectly - when I run the test and print the response the Nokogiri::XML(open(url)) always yields   `<?xml version="1.0"?>`
totally ignoring whatever xml is actually there.  This only happens wtih nokogiri, if i run httparty I do not get this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Nokogiri::XML(open(url))` does work with `open-uri` and a valid url. How is `url` defined? You should post more code and more information on what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

The code `Nokogiri::XML( open(url) )` has two steps: 1) `open(url)` to load the response, and 2) `Nokogiri::XML( response )` to parse the XML structure. I'd troubleshoot these two steps separately. What happens when you just run `open(url)` and point it to the URL in question? If you open up the Rails console, can you use `open(url)` to get hold of the full XML content? If not, can you use `open(url)` passing in a valid HTML URL (like "www.google.com") to get a valid HTML response? This will help you figure out whether the issue is with *loading* the XML data, or with *parsing* it. And if the issue is with *loading* the XML data, then your question doesn't really involve Nokogiri anymore and it will be simpler to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi, Yes I have tested it that way.  The problem isn't that I don't get a response.  I do.  When I run it in console and actually run the function it works fine.  THe problem is when I do it with RSPEC it doesn't work.  Basically everything works fine until I do it with rspec.  I am using Sinatra, but I have enabled_net_connect and still nothing

Comment: Hm interesting. But it still sounds like it's extraneous (and confusing to us SO answerers!) to include Nokogiri::XML in the equation... it sounds like the problem is with fetching the raw response data, not with parsing the XML, correct? If so I think it would be worth editing your question, or perhaps asking a brand new question since this one doesn't seem to really get at the central issue.

Comment: Another idea: Use the `pry` gem or similar to get a console session running *inside* your test suite. Then you can manually try running requests there and confirm that the same exact command (like `open(url)`) yields a different response when you're in the plain Rails console vs. in the middle of a spec. If you can demonstrate that, and provide steps to repeat it, then I think you'll get much more specific advice here.